# /var/log mounted as a tmpfs failing to get umounted on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, syslog, file-descriptors, tmpfs, unix-sockets

I have `/var/log` mounted as a tmpfs, where log files are synced periodically to the disk by the cron on FreeBSD. The process is done by the `rc` script.

I am mounting it like:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o nosuid,noexec,mode=0755,size=100M log /var/log
```

Now the problem is - unmounting it. It fails to unmount, because `(r)syslog` writes to the file. This is shown by lsof:

```
 lsof /var/log/
lsof: WARNING: compiled for FreeBSD release 11.1-RELEASE-p6; this is 11.1-RELEASE.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE         DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rsyslogd 85515 root    2w  VREG 255,2264924190      210   13 /var/log/security
rsyslogd 85515 root    4w  VREG 255,2264924190      210    3 /var/log/auth.log
rsyslogd 85515 root    5w  VREG 255,2264924190     2292    7 /var/log/kern.notice
rsyslogd 85515 root    6w  VREG 255,2264924190     2292   11 /var/log/messages
rsyslogd 85515 root    7w  VREG 255,2264924190     2292    5 /var/log/debug.log
```

So in order to unmount it, firstly I have to stop the syslog daemon. However, I am looking for some nicer solution, as this actions are managed by a sh rc script itself.

On the Linux/GNU Os's `umount` has a very handy argument: 
`--lazy detach the filesystem now, clean up things later`

, which by my knowledge, waits for an active processes to stop r/w to the filesystem, and *then* process with unmounting it, which would result in success and not breaking the script.

So as a workaround to this, how can I stop syslog temporary writing to /var/log ? I've tried issuing `STOP`, trying to umount  and `CONT` signal, but no effect.

Lsof still reports that there are FD that are open to writing. Note that I need solution that can be applicable from `sh` script.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The umount has `--force` argument, which under normal circumstances I would avoid at any cost.
But since this is a `tmpfs` and runs from a memory not block device, I believe it will do no harm.

Couple of tests showed that there are no issues. I did it by creating dummy files on tmpfs with `dd`, checked their sums, sync them to hdd, and then forcing the umount.
The hashes matched which means that files weren't corrupted.

Well that is kinda dirty workaround, but I am not aware of other solutions. If someone has some drawbacks against this method on ram fs, please let me know.

*ps: kudos to @layer8problem for advices :-)*

Comment: Why do you use tmpfs instead of writing the logs directly to the disk?

Comment: Because I am running in on embedded, to save sdcard life.

Comment: your embedded device will quickly run out of ram if you syslog to a tmpfs.  have you considered remote syslog to another machine on the network?

Comment: @cas Well, yes probably, but I have "plenty" of ram for this, as this being done on rpi2, also, logs are pretty much reduced to say. I am aware for the network loging, but not usable for me atm. Anyway, after talking with some people on #freebsd I've got a "solution". Will update my question.

Comment: @fugitive: you wrote: "synced periodically to the *disk*" - I think you should redirect your logs to this *disk*. Or isn't possible? Or can you mount (maybe nullfs) your disk to `/var/log`?

Comment: Alternatively, set up a log server that receives the logs from the device and let it save the logs directly to disk.